# How to run docker run -d --name oraclefree in Docker with Rosetta enabled on macOS Sonoma Apple Silicon M1 Pro?

Tags: oracle, docker, macos, macos-sonoma

How to run docker run -d --name oraclefree in Docker with Rosetta enabled on macOS Sonoma Apple Silicon M1 Pro?

**% docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest**

**docker run syntax:**

```
docker run -d --name container_name 
 -p host_port:1521 -p host_port:5500 
 -e ORACLE_SID=cdb-system-identifer 
 -e ORACLE_PDB=pdb-name 
 -e ORACLE_PWD=oracle-user-password 
 -e INIT_SGA_SIZE=cdb-database-sga-memory-in-mb 
 -e INIT_PGA_SIZE=cdb-database-pga-memory-in-mb 
 -e ORACLE_EDITION=ee-or-se-database-edition 
 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=character-set 
 -e ENABLE_ARCHIVELOG=[true|false]
 -v [host-mount-point:]/opt/oracle/oradata 
container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:21.3.0
```

```
docker run -d --name oraclefree 
 -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 
 -e ORACLE_SID=cdb-system-identifer 
 -e ORACLE_PDB=pdb-name 
 -e ORACLE_PWD=oracle-user-password 
container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
```

```
docker exec -it oraclefree sqlplus sys/oracle-user-password@cdb-system-identifer as sysdba
```

Please refer to the following **terminal output** for details:

```
Last login: Fri Nov 10 16:23:30 on ttys000
% sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.0
BuildVersion:       23A344
% arch
arm64
% docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:28:49 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.25.0 (126437)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:31:36 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
% docker info   
Client:
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2-desktop.5
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.23.0-desktop.1
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.20
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.9
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-init
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.26.0
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan
  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.9
    Path:     /Users/macosm1pro/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 24.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc version: v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.4.16-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.661GiB
 Name: linuxkit-926b11cd7cb0
 ID: a54ccb6e-4130-495b-a99b-1bcd8b208a56
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile
% docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest      
latest: Pulling from database/free
089fdfcd47b7: Pull complete 
43c899d88edc: Pull complete 
47aa6f1886a1: Pull complete 
f8d07bb55995: Pull complete 
c31c8c658c1e: Pull complete 
b7d28faa08b4: Pull complete 
1d0d5c628f6f: Pull complete 
db82a695dad3: Pull complete 
25a185515793: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:5ac0efa9896962f6e0e91c54e23c03ae8f140cf6ed43ca09ef4354268a942882
Status: Downloaded newer image for container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
% docker run -d --name oraclefree \
 -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 \
 -e ORACLE_SID=cdb-system-identifer \
 -e ORACLE_PDB=pdb-name \
 -e ORACLE_PWD=oracle-user-password \
container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
299d6fe0f0403b217382b501f77b35f475b46ed373595390b861ca85a5c37dc4
% docker exec -it oraclefree sqlplus sys/oracle-user-password@cdb-system-identifer as sysdba
Error response from daemon: Container 299d6fe0f0403b217382b501f77b35f475b46ed373595390b861ca85a5c37dc4 is not running
%
```

Comment: Do not use Ubuntu. Oracle server is only supported on Red Hat Linux and derivatives like Oracle Linux or SuSE Enterprise. To run on M1 you need something to emulate the x86 chip architecture and to run a VM with Oracle Linux (which is free). It won't run natively on MacOS or any other flavor of Linux, or on the ARM chipset without emulation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Colima for emulation due to the the M1s being ARM. Give this a whirl https://github.com/abiosoft/colima and it will boot, although don't expect much in terms of performance. Oracle will release an ARM compatible version, hopefully sometime in 2024.